# focus goto on next box after enter character in first box

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have to implement an application in which I have set small `edittext` for input PIN number and Mobile Number. Each edit text contain 1 character at a time.
Now when I run this app, I found that for each box I need to give focus to each `edittext`. 
So in this case is it possible to set focus in next edittext after character  is entered in first and then goto third after character is entered in second.
so please help me out this

Here is layout image.

[image]

Comment: Implement TextWatcher to your edittext and get the length of entered character when its 1 change focus to next view.

Comment: check http://www.technotalkative.com/android-about-edittext-textwatcher/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1. implements TextWatcher on EditTexts
```

and then when you get Edittext's text **length is 1**.

```
2. Change focus on other EditText using
```

Call `requestFocus()` on the other EditText..

**CODE:** (This code is for your understanding, It may be different on your case and your need)

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher
{
 .
 .
 .

  editTextUName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttextusername);
  editTextUName.addTextChangedListener(this);
  editTextPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttextpassword);
  editTextPwd.addTextChangedListener(this);

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    if (s.toString().length() == 1)
    {
              editTextPwd.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please give me one example

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
final EditText EditText01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText01);
final EditText EditText02= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText02);
final EditText EditText03 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText03);
final EditText EditText04 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText04);

EditText01.requestFocus();
EditText01.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(final View v,
                            final boolean hasFocus) {

                        if (hasFocus) {
                            final InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is
                            // open
                            mgr.showSoftInput(EditText01,
                                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                        }

                    }
                });

        EditText01.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(final View v, final int keyCode,
                    final KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        EditText01.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        EditText02.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        EditText02.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(final View v, final int keyCode,
                    final KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        EditText01.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        EditText03.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        EditText03.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(final View v, final int keyCode,
                    final KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        EditText02.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        EditText04.requestFocus();
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        EditText04.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(final View v, final int keyCode,
                    final KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        EditText03.requestFocus();
                    } 

                }

                return false;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a text change listener

```
      textView1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               textView2.requestFocus();

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,             int after) {
             }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.
mPinFirst and so on are the EditTexts representing each Pin entry.
Should also take care of backspacing.

```
    mPinFirst.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener);
    mPinSecond.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener);
    mPinThird.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener);
    mPinFourth.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener);




View.OnKeyListener onKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL != keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
            if (((ESEditText) view).getText().length() == 1)
                if (view.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT) != null) {
                    view.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT).requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
        }else{
            ((ESEditText) view).setText("");
            if (view.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_LEFT) != null) {
                view.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_LEFT).requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```